# How to judge a special matrix is a positive-definite-matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

I came across a matrix and I need to prove it is a positive-definite-matrix

the matrix is $(a_{i,j})_{n\times n }$ where $ 0\leq  i\leq n-1$ and $ 0\leq  j\leq n-1$
$a_{i,j}=\beta_1^{i+j}+\beta_2^{i+j}$ where $1<\beta_1<\beta_2<2$ are fixed.

Comment: when n=2 it is true because all the eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: Your matrix is symmetric, hence diagonalizable. All you need to show is that the eigenvalues are positive. Can you do that? (I'm not sure it's the right way to go though.) You might wanna use the fact that you can write 
$$
(a_{ij}) = (\beta_1^{i+j}) + (\beta_2^{i+j})
$$
because those matrices ($(\beta_k^{i+j})$, $k=1,2$) look easier to work with. I'd guess that they are semi-positive definite (their determinant is zero, so they can't be definite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the matrix $(\beta_k^{i+j})$, $k=1,2$, $0 \le i,j \le n-1$. One can clearly find an explicit form for its eigenvectors, which will be given by 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\beta_k^{n-1} & -\beta_k^{n-2} & \dots  & -\beta_k & \frac {1}{\beta_k^{n-1}} \\
       0       &       0        & \dots  & 1        & \frac {1}{\beta_k^{n-2}} \\
       \vdots  &                & \ddots &          & \vdots \\
       1       &      \dots     & \dots  &          & \frac {1}{\beta_k^0}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
(The column vectors are the eigenvectors, the first $n-1$ eigenvectors have eigenvalue $0$ and the last one has eigenvalue $n \beta_k^{n-1}$. The diagonal dots should go from bottom left to top right, didn't know how to format them...)

Since its eigenvalues are all non-negative, the matrix is semi-positive definite. Let $v \in \mathbb R^n$. Then if $A = (a_{ij})$ and $B_k = (\beta_k^{i+j})$, then 
$$
v^{\top} A v = v^{\top} B_1 v + v^{\top} B_2 v \ge 0
$$
by what we have just shown. Assume that $v^{\top} A v = 0$, which means $v^{\top} B_1 v = v^{\top} B_2 v = 0$. By the spectral theorem, we can write
$$
V_1^0 \oplus V_1^{n\beta_1^{n-1}} = \mathbb R^n = V_2^0 \oplus V_2^{n\beta_1^{n-1}}
$$
where the $V_k^{\lambda}$ are the eigenspaces of $B_k$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ and those subspaces are orthogonal. Notice how the kernel of $B_k$ has dimension $n-1$, so 
$$
\dim( (\ker B_1) \cap (\ker B_2) ) \ge n-2.
$$
Therefore, for $n \ge 3$, this intersection has dimension $\ge 1$, so we can find a vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $B_1 v = B_2 v = 0$, hence $v^{\top} Av = 0$ and $A$ is *not* positive definite for $n \ge 3$, although it is semi-positive definite.

For $n=2$, the condition $\beta_1 < \beta_2$ ensures that the eigenvectors of $B_1$ from the eigenvalue $n\beta_1^{n-1}$ and of $B_2$ from the eigenvalue $n\beta_2^{n-2}$ are not colinear, hence they give a basis of $\mathbb R^2$ and thus for any $v \in \mathbb R^2 \backslash \{0\}$, we have
$$
v^{\top} A v \ge \max\{ v^{\top} B_1 v, v^{\top} B_2 v \} > 0
$$ 
because $v$ has a non-zero component in one of the two eigenvectors.

P.S. You might as well have assumed $\beta_1, \beta_2 > 0$ and $\beta_1 \neq \beta_2$ instead of $1 < \beta_1 < \beta_2 < 2$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: You have proved the matirx A is semi-positive definite, and this is equalivent to all the eigenvalues are non-negative,and I think the next step is to calculate the determinant of A, because if $|A|\neq=0$,then all the eigenvalues are positive,so A is positive definite.

Comment: I have shown that for $n \ge 3$, the matrix $A$ is semi-positive definite but **not** positive definite. All the steps are there ; there are no next steps. For $n = 2$ though the matrix is positive definite as we both found out separately.

Comment: and I want to ask you that can you find a vector $v$ such that $B_1v=B_2v=0$ where the coordinates of $v$  are $\{-1\,,0\,,1\}$? of course the non-zero vectors.

Comment: Um, your last question makes no sense ; if you give me $v$ I can't find you some other $v'$ such that $v' = v$ and $v'$ has extra properties that $v$ doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

The  matrix $(c_ic_j)$ is semipositive definite as well as $(c_ic_j)+(d_id_j).$ Apply this to $c_i=\beta_1^i$ and $d_i=\beta_2^i.$ Of course its rank is $\leq 2$ and the matrix cannot be positive definite if $n
\geq 3.$